# How do I continue editing a draft in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a unfinished message saved as a draft in Microsoft Outlook 2010. I want to finish writing the draft and send it out, but I don't see any option to edit my draft after it has been saved.

**How can I continue editing an email draft in Microsoft Outlook?**

[image: Viewing draft in Outlook 2010]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just double-click on it; that will open it up for editing in a separate window.

Comment: Well now I feel a bit silly for not figuring that out earlier.

Comment: What's a bad UX !!

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI - If you really think it's that bad, write your Ph.D. dissertationon UI design and propose a better way...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  Your answer was already voted up. The bad is the UX of µSoft not your answer 

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI - I understood that; my point is that if you think it's a bad UI on Microsoft's part, propose a better one - I certainly can't think of one that wouldn't be more complex from both the user standpoint _and_ the code standpoint.

Comment: You convinced me. I totally agree.