# How to edit mail from drafts folder created with K9?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2016

I used [K9](https://k9mail.github.io/) to start writing a mail. Then I saved it as draft on my IMAP account. How do I open that draft for editing using Outlook 2016?

Problem: When I double click the item as proposed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1231465/how-do-i-continue-editing-a-draft-in-outlook), it is opened as "received" mail - I cannot edit it. Right click gives me this menu:

[image]

Sorry, it is in German but it is the [same as in the question linked above](https://superuser.com/questions/1231465/how-do-i-continue-editing-a-draft-in-outlook).

Please note the difference:

- The second draft you see in the screenshot shows an edit symbol and no time. This draft I created with Outlook. Double clicking it allows me to edit it.
- The first draft was the one created with K9. It contains a time (4:05pm). Is this the reason why Outlook "thinks" it is a received mail rather than a draft?
  Is there an easy solution? Or is a change in either Outlook or K9 required?

Comment: What’s your account type? POP or IMAP? We can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter.

Comment: IMAP. Same in safe mode. There I could see that the time belongs to attribute `sent`. I guess that K9 and Outlook are using IMAP attributes differently and thus do not play together nicely.

Comment: Do you create the draft on the web mail of K5? If you direct create a draft on Outlook client, will same issue occur?

Comment: K9 is an Android app - see link above; no web mail. Concerning "If you direct create a draft on Outlook client": That works - see question above starting with: "The second draft..."

Comment: can you edit the draft on the web mail?